# SQL Server 2016 SP1 CU1 Install Fails

Tags: sql-server, installation, sql-server-2016, clustering

I am trying to install CU1 for SQL Server 2016 SP1 on a clustered node and it fails with an error that I am not able to find information on. In the summary log file it has the following:

> Instance MSSQLSERVER overall summary:
>   Final result:                  The patch installer has failed to update the shared features. To
>   determine the reason for failure, review the log files.
>   Exit code (Decimal):           -2146233079
>   Exit facility code:            19 
>   Exit error code:               5385
>   Exit message:                  The given key was not present in the dictionary.
>   Start time:         2017-02-14 10:02:56
>   End time:                      2017-02-14
>   10:03:18
>   Requested action:              Patch

When I look in the detail log, I am not seeing anything that is helpful (at least to me). There are a lot of occurrences of these lines before the error,

"Sco: Attempting to..."
and 
"Skipping service control for the following instance because it has one or more clustered features: MSSQLSERVER"

I installed this CU to another cluster without any issues. The only difference between them, the one that it succeeded on was 2016 Standard with SP1, and the one that does not work is 2016 Developer with SP1.

Comment: Seems a bit odd to me that you have different editions in the same cluster.

Comment: Not different editions in the same cluster. I had setup a cluster for 2016 standard for our production environment, and am setting up a new cluster with 2016 developer for development environment. They are entirely different clusters.

Comment: Is the dev instance running when you apply the CU? Or is it stopped?

Comment: The "skipping service control" log line may not actually be an issue. But do you see any thing like the bold lines in both logs shown at https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/96af5ac3-9fdc-45a3-beb9-4d405b4ccbf5/error-installing-cumulative-update-3-for-sql-server-2008-r2-sp2?forum=sqlsetupandupgrade ?

Comment: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/178346/design-a-db-table-where-rows-may-have-null-in-multiple-column

Answer (score 1):

The installer that I was initially using was SQL Server 2016 Developer with SP1. When I would try and apply CU1 for SP1 it was failing. I downloaded the SQL Server 2016 Developer RTM and installed it. I then applied SP1, rebooted and applied CU1 for SP1 and that worked. What I am not sure of is why there is a difference between the two scenarios.

Comment: Doesn't SP 1 include CU 1.  https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlreleaseservices/sql-server-2016-service-pack-1-sp1-released/.    Or is it CU1 for SP1?  https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3208177/cumulative-update-1-for-sql-server-2016-sp1